# SPARQL: How do you pass a variable into a subquery?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This works:

```
SELECT ?propLabel ?val WHERE {
    BIND("incoming"@en AS ?propLabel)
    {
      SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?val) WHERE {
        ?s ?p wd:Q8740.
        _:b72 wikibase:directClaim ?p.
      }
    }
}
```

But this does not, I assume because the sub-query is evaluated first, and therefore `?entity` is not bound yet:

```
SELECT ?propLabel ?val WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q8740 as ?entity)
    BIND("incoming"@en AS ?propLabel)
    {
      SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?val) WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?entity.
        _:b72 wikibase:directClaim ?p.
      }
    }
}
```

If so, how do we "pass" a variable into a subquery?

Comment: that's not how subqueries work. it's bottom up evaluation. what prevents you from using the URI directly in the subquery? I don't get the problem

Comment: @AKSW This is a small section of a large query that contains a large number of places where the subject is required. As I test the query in the Wikidata query editor, it'd be insane to manually replace every instance of the subject, so it's much more feasible to use a variable to hold the subject.

Comment: I think what you're aiming for is a parameterized SPARQL query, which I do not believe can be done with pure SPARQL. Different tools (such as Jena, or Virtuoso's SPASQL a/k/a SPARQL-in-SQL) provide different ways to do such parameterization outside SPARQL.

Comment: [Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FpropLabel%20%3Fval%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%20%28wd%3AQ8740%20AS%20%3Fentity%29%0A%20%20BIND%28%22incoming%22%40en%20AS%20%3FpropLabel%29%0A%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28COUNT%28%3Fs%29%20AS%20%3Fval%29%20%3Fentity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fentity.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%5D%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fp.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fentity%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D). In that particular case, optimizer works well.

Comment: Yeah; I can do the templating in my script, but I just wanted to see if there was some "official" way to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the *Optimizations in Blazegraph* section in the [*SPARQL Bottom Up Semantics*](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics#Optimizations_in_Blazegraph) article, then help the optimizer slightly:

```sql
SELECT ?propLabel ?val WHERE {
  BIND (wd:Q8740 AS ?entity)
  BIND("incoming"@en AS ?propLabel)
  { 
    SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?val) ?entity WHERE {
      ?s ?p ?entity .
      [] wikibase:directClaim ?p 
    } GROUP BY ?entity
  } 
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FpropLabel%20%3Fval%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%20%28wd%3AQ8740%20AS%20%3Fentity%29%0A%20%20BIND%28%22incoming%22%40en%20AS%20%3FpropLabel%29%0A%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28COUNT%28%3Fs%29%20AS%20%3Fval%29%20%3Fentity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fentity.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%5D%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fp.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fentity%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D)

Just add the `?entity` variable to the projection (and then you should `GROUP BY` `?entity` explicitely).
As a result, you will have additional `joinVars=[entity]` in the [query plan](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?explain&query=SELECT%20%3FpropLabel%20%3Fval%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%20(wd%3AQ8740%20AS%20%3Fentity)%0A%20%20BIND(%22incoming%22%40en%20AS%20%3FpropLabel)%0A%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20(COUNT(%3Fs)%20AS%20%3Fval)%20%3Fentity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fentity.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20[]%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fp.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fentity%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D).

It's interesting that such optimization can not be disabled using `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you; I don't understand this yet but it gives me something to chew on ;)

Comment: In short, don't care. Blazegraph optimizer do its job almost every time when it is possible, except for hard cases like aggregates etc, when it needs some help.